# FakeItEasy - How to have an interface fake inherit from abstract?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, fakeiteasy

I have an interface

```
interface IInterface {}
```

An abstract class

```
abstract class AbstractClass : IInterface { }
```

Concrete class

```
class Irrelevant { Irrelevant (IInterface service) {} }
```

I'm writing a unit test against `Irrelevant` and the abstract class already contains helpful methods I'd want to leverage for my unit test. How would I make my `A.Fake<IInterface>();` inherit from `AbstractClass`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var fake = A.Fake<AbstractClass>();
```

That's how FakeItEasy makes fakes - by having [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) subclass an existing class.
(When an interface is faked, it subclasses System.Object.)

Comment: This wasn't quite the question I wanted to ask - was in a rush to leave the office and ended up writing the wrong question. I did accept it because it was the right answer, thank you!!!

Comment: I created a new question with what I actually wanted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697918/fakeiteasy-having-an-interface-fake-inherit-from-abstract-while-both-share-sam