# FakeItEasy - Having an interface fake inherit from abstract while both share same interface inheritance

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, fakeiteasy

I have an interface

```
public interface IInterface { void DoSomething(); }
```

Another interface

```
public interface IOtherInterface : IInterface { }
```

An abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractClass : IInterface
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got here");
    }
}
```

I'm writing a unit test and fake IOtherInterface. The abstract class already contains helpful methods I'd want to leverage for my unit test. How would I make my `A.Fake<IOtherInterface>();` inherit from `AbstractClass`?

This is what I've tried so far but it doesn't work - AbstractClass.DoSomething does not get hit.

```
        IOtherInterface fake = A.Fake<IOtherInterface>(builder => builder.Implements(typeof (AbstractClass)));

        fake.DoSomething();
```

Of course if I make a proxy like:

```
        var abstractFake = A.Fake<AbstractClass>();
        A.CallTo(() => fake.DoSomething()).Invokes(abstractFake.DoSomething);

        fake.DoSomething();
```

... things work as I wanted. Is there a built in mechanism to achieve this so that I don't need that proxy `abstractFake` object?

**UPDATE**

I need `IOtherInterface` because I have a client class that needs that IOtherInterface as dependency:

```
class Consumer
{
    public Consumer(IOtherInterface otherInterface)
    {
        otherInterface.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: It does, however `abstractFake` variable will be of type `AbstractClass` and not `IOtherInterface`. I need `IOtherInterface`. See update :)

Comment: Thanks for raising this question. As you can see from Blair Conrad's answer, two project issues have been raised as a result, which is great!

Comment: @AdamRalph I'll be honest, it blew my mind to see the Blair's pro activity by going and creating those project issues, something you normally don't see. Normally even collaborators of a project would just say "go file a bug" of sorts. Anyway, I'm glad I have indirectly contributed :)

Comment: Indeed, Blair Conrad is a huge asset to any project!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var fake = (IOtherInterface) A.Fake<AbstractClass>(builder =>
                               builder.Implements(typeof(IOtherInterface)));
A.CallTo(() => fake.DoSomething()).CallsBaseMethod();
fake.DoSomething();
```

`Implements` is intended to work only with interfaces, so the proper way to use it is to fake an interface or class and use `Implements` to add additional interface. I think it should've complained at you, so I raised [complain when IFakeOptionsBuilder.Implements is passed a non-interface](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/462), **which was fixed in FakeItEasy 2.0.0**.

The `CallsBaseMethod` will ensure that the Abstract class's method is executed.

I would've recommended `builder.CallsBaseMethods()`, but this fails to redirect the call. I think it's because it's redirecting `AbstractClass.DoSomething`, but when we cast the fake to `IOtherInterface` and call `DoSomething`, it's not matching. I've raised [investigate interaction between `Implements` and `CallsBaseMethods`](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/463).

Comment: Thanks @blairconrad for helping, for being proactive raising the complaint/investigation. I'm not aware of the release cycle of FakeItEasy but I'm looking forward for these issues to be fixed. :)

Comment: @JoaoMilasch, FakeItEasy usually [releases frequently](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FakeItEasy), but as with many open source projects, the schedule depends on the availability of the core team and rate of contributions from the community.
I wouldn't necessarily expect a _speedy_ resolution, as the core team are involved in the upcoming 2.0 release, and these issues are quite minor. One is effectively "add a warning message to let users know they used Implements wrong" and the other is quite a corner case-an interaction between two not minor features, and it has a workaround.

Comment: fair enough. I'm ok with the work around anyway. Thanks for helping.